# Data Doesn't Save In MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have a .NET Web API (C#) where I can GET and POST data (Obviously). When I make a GET request, it returns all the data which it is supposed to. I have made my methods/functions to return a bool if a sql command worked. So when I make a PUT or POST request it returns true (which means it worked).

Then if I make a GET request or if I SELECT all in SQL Management Studio, the data hasn't saved. However Delete works.

This did work but stopped, all of a sudden.

This is my Add/POST method:

```
    public bool Add(string id, byte[] bytes)
    {
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [ag_Images] ([Id], [Data]) VALUES (@Id, @Data)");
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
        return _Sql.Execute(Command);
    }
```

Which passes a SqlCommand to:

```
    SqlTransaction _Transaction;

    public bool Execute(SqlCommand Command)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AptestDB"].ConnectionString);
        using (conn)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                _Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction("SQL_Execution");
                Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                Command.Connection = conn;
                Command.Transaction = _Transaction;
                try
                {
                    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    _Transaction.Commit();
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    _Transaction.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

The above doesn't work. However, this does (SQL Management Studio)

```
DECLARE @Id VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Data VARBINARY(MAX)

SET @Id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
SET @Data = CAST('' AS VARBINARY)

UPDATE [ag_Images] SET [Data] = @Data WHERE [Id] = @Id
```

**UPDATE**

I have removed the SqlTransaction, so far things are working.

Comment: You do nothing with possible errors in the `catch` block. Maybe there is an error message but you will never be notified. Handle the exception message to see what's happening.

Comment: I have checked already, there are no apparent errors. @VDWWD

Comment: Did you debug the code to check exception?

Comment: I debugged it, but no exceptions were thrown. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Sounds like the credentials you are using to connect to SQL do not have all the rights necessary to insert.

Comment: The code looks ok. Are you sure you are debugging both the catch blocks to check the exception? Also you are running update query in sql management studio while code tries to run insert query. Are you able to run insert comand from sql management studio ?

Comment: @Franck I've been using this method and connection string for a while now. It works but keeps stop working, then works again

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes. All commands work in Sql Management Studio

Comment: You're catching the exceptions but not persisting them anywhere. Don't do that. *Log exceptions*. And certainly there's no reason for such a low level method to be catching exceptions. Let them bubble up to the point where you can actually take some different action based on the exception.

Comment: Firstly, I'd check your database for any new triggers or similar unattended code execution. It's possible there's a trigger deleting or updating your records, which explains why you can't find them afterwards.
Secondly, I'd put a fair amount of logging code into your API, for both the "happy" and "unhappy" path.
Thirdly, I'd try to re-create this in a unit/integration test, so it's easier to debug

Comment: I have removed the SqlTransaction and so far things are working how they should do.

Answer (score 1):

The saving method can return true even if the insert operation did not succeed - ExecuteNonQuery value can be -1 under certain conditions (i.e. triggers, constraints), which can mean (unless NOCOUNT is on, in which case the return value is always -1) that no rows were affected/inserted.

Modify the code to not lie to you anymore:

```
var rowsInserted = Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (rowsInserted > 0)
{
    _Transaction.Commit();
    return true;
}
else
{
    _Transaction.Rollback();
    return false;
}
```

or

```
var rowsInserted = Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
_Transaction.Commit(); //with -1 result, no changes are done anyway
return rowsInserted > 0;
```

If it were me:

- I would check with a SQL Profiler that the command actually reaches
  the SQL server.
- I would trace/log the result of ExecuteNonQuery and try to correlate that with other activities. If it were a timing issue...
- When you say debugging, you mean with all Managed Debug Assistants activated?

***UPDATE***
If removing the transaction is not satisfactory for you later on, I noticed another issue with the initial code. If removing it works, I now suspect that the actual issue was with transactions left hanging because of object reference being overwritten in the Execute method call:

```
_Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction("SQL_Execution");
```

If there are 2 or more threads competing for this, trouble is ensured.

Why not declare the Transaction in the method itself:

```
var _Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction("SQL_Execution");
```

Comment: I've declared the transaction inside the method. It seems to work

Comment: Good to hear! Now you get to keep the transaction goodness if you so choose! There are pluses and minuses, as in all things in programming, so you will have to decide if you keep it or not, but at least now we know the "why" of your initial question. :)